# How to count the amount of times an object in a list appears N times in a row?

Tags: python-3.x

So, what I'm doing here is I'm generating 1000 coin tosses, and putting these tosses in a list. What I'm then trying to do is find how many times heads was tossed 3 times in a row, or tails was tossed 3 times in a row. My attempt:

```
toss_count = 0
trips_count = 0
coin_tosses = []
while toss_count < 1000:
    toss = random.randint(1, 2)
    if toss == 1:
        coin_tosses.append("heads")
        toss_count += 1
    elif toss == 2:
        coin_tosses.append("tails")
        toss_count += 1
```

so up until here the code is doing what I want. My problem occurs with what I'm trying to do next though:

```
for trips in coin_tosses:
    if "'heads', 'heads', 'heads'" in coin_tosses:
        trips_count += 1
print(trips_count)
```

Something like this clearly does not work, but I don't know how else to achieve what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: How would you count overlaps, i.e. more the 3x in a row: `H H H H`?

Comment: My assignment tells me to first solve the problem at hand, and count H H H H as two times 3x in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code that slice array every item in it that takes three items every item `coin_tosses[counter:counter+3]`

```
toss_count = 0
trips_count = 0
coin_tosses = []
while toss_count < 1000:
    toss = random.randint(1, 2)
    if toss == 1:
        coin_tosses.append("heads")
        toss_count += 1
    elif toss == 2:
        coin_tosses.append("tails")
        toss_count += 1

print(coin_tosses)

counter = 0
for trips in coin_tosses:
    if ['heads', 'heads', 'heads'] == coin_tosses[counter:counter+3]:
        trips_count += 1
    counter +=1

print(trips_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate through, checking whether the value is the same as the previous two. I think this should work. It counts the total number of triples, regardless of whether they're heads or tails, which your code seems to suggest is what you're after. Can easily add a check if you need them seperately.

```
trips_count = 0
previous_value = None
value_before_that = None
for current_value in coin_tosses:
    if (current_value == previous_value) and (current_value == value_before_that):
        trips_count += 1
    value_before_that = previous_value
    previous_value = current_value
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this:*

```
import random
toss_count = 0
trips_count = 0
coin_tosses = []
while toss_count < 1000:
    toss = random.randint(1, 2)
    if toss == 1:
        coin_tosses.append("heads")
        toss_count += 1
    elif toss == 2:
        coin_tosses.append("tails")
        toss_count += 1

for i in range(len(coin_tosses)-2):
    if coin_tosses[i] == coin_tosses[i+1] == coin_tosses[i+2]:
        trips_count += 1

print(trips_count)
```